# Query String Parameter 'URL' Containing URL with a Query String

Tags: facebook

In context to the answer of 'Alo Sarv' at this question:-

[Why is Facebook share button pulling parameters from the meta tags instead of my specified ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694384/why-is-facebook-share-button-pulling-parameters-from-the-meta-tags-instead-of-my)

I'm facing a problem.

How can I achieve this:-

```
http://siteA.com?siteA_URL=http://siteB.com?siteB_title=abc&siteB_description=def&siteA_title=ghi&siteA_description=jkl
```

Such that siteA_URL is

```
siteA_URL = http://siteB.com?siteB_title=abc&siteB_description=def
```

and not:-

```
siteA_URL = http://siteB.com?siteB_title=abc
```

Comment: Is this a javascript question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly encode the URL parameter:

```
var siteA_URL = encodeURIComponent("http://siteB.com?siteB_title=abc&siteB_description=def");
var url = "http://siteA.com?siteA_URL=" + siteA_URL;
```